# Using static and dynamic version of the same template in shopify

Tags: shopify

I was trying to test the limitations of the Shopify's sections and I was left facing an issue.

Whenever I included one or more static section of a type in the homepage, if there were already dynamic sections of that same type, the one inserted later in the page would show up as a blank whitespace.

Is it not possible to use a static and a dynamic version of the same section in the same template?

For example, making index.liquid

```
{% section 'slideshow' %}
{{ content_for_index }}
```

Where settings_data.json contains a 'slideshow' in the sections.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow you.

When you use a static section the information for the section is saved in the `settings_data.json` file. So when you use that section any where else it will use the same information that was entered.

When you use a dynamic section that information is saved in `settings_data.json` once again but the content for each sections is different and you can have different content for the same section.

That said when you use a static section and dynamic section together the content between them is NOT shared. So when you use a dynamic section that is set as a static section the content will not be passed from the static section to the dynamic section, so that's why your section is blank.

I assume this is the issue you are describing.